# VSCode Prettier Extension vs Command Line Prettier

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I have an issue where HTML file formatting in VSCode, "on-save", is different than Prettier's formatting when using the command line.

My user settings (changing these values doesn't seem to make any difference):

```
{
    "[html]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
    },
    "prettier.eslintIntegration": false,
    "html.format.enable": false
}
```

When I run Prettier from the command line, my HTML gets formatted like this:

```
prettier --write "./src/app/my-file.html"
```

my-file.html:

```
<a ng-hide="$last" href="" ng-click="doThis(thing)"
  >{{ crumb.title }}</a
>
```

The same code when I save the file in VSCode (allowing the Prettier extension to do the formatting):

```
<a ng-hide="$last" href="" ng-click="doThis(thing)">{{
  crumb.title
}}</a>
```

I know the extension is installed and working, because I see this icon in the bottom right hand side of the screen:

[image]

And, when I hover over this icon, I see a tooltip that says `prettier@1.16.3`, the same version I have installed on the command line `prettier -v`

Why am I getting different results with these 2 methods? I have not altered any settings, other than the above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I needed to create a `.prettierrc` file with the following contents:

```
{
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": "*.html",
      "options": {
        "parser": "html"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The command line was using the `html` parser, while VSCode was using the `angular` parser. This way they are both using the same parser for `.html` files.

Comment: Bless you for finding this! I've been bashing my head against this for days. My `prettier --check .` and `prettier --write .` were conflicting with the plugin.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer your own question, it was helpful!